# Linux getpwnam() library dependencies

Tags: c, linux

I had a program whose system call `getpwnam()` was failing at runtime.  To debug this, I decided to run `getpwnam()` in isolation with this code (it came from a forum):

```
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
struct passwd *pw;

if (argc != 2) {
    printf("usage: %s username\n", argv[0]);
    exit(0);
}
pw = getpwnam(argv[1]);
if (pw == NULL)
    printf("getpwnam failed\n");
else
    printf("home dir = %s\n", pw->pw_dir);
    exit(0);
}
```

Oddly it seems to depend on `libnss_compat-2.3.5.so` being present:

**With libnss_compat:**

`./pwnam root
home dir = /root`

**Without libnss_compat:**

`./pwnam root
getpwnam failed`

So my question is; why is `getpwnam()` dependent on `libnss_compat*.so`?  I found out with the `nm -D` command that `libc-2.3.5.so` is the lib which provides `getpwnam()`.

`readelf -d` shows me that `libc` in turn only depends on `ld.so.1`.  That in turn depends on nothing.  So why on earth is `libnss_compat` having an impact?

Thanks for your help everyone!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NSS is the Name Service Switch, a library that can look up user information in various sources (traditional password files, [Network Information Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Information_Service), LDAP). `getpwnam` may be defined in `libc`, but that will load the actual NSS library at runtime. Looking inside `libc`, I find

```
$ strings /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep libnss
libnss_
libnss_
libnss_%s.so.%d.%d
```

The last line is clearly a format string for `snprintf` that is used to construct the name of the actual implementation library to load using `dlopen`. The implementation is determined using `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

**EDIT** I found the place in the Glibc sources where [the library is loaded](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nss/nsswitch.c;h=07ca2252321c57e98023b87f129d9a4acddf9055;hb=HEAD#l324). It's not (no longer?) using `snprintf`, but the principle is still the same.

Comment: Also note that how the lookup is done, and what modules to load for doing the lookup is normally configured in /etc/nsswitch.conf on linux

Comment: Thanks!  But in the future, if my programs are not working, how am I supposed to know that library-abc depends on library-xyz if it doesn't show up with `readelf -d`?

Comment: @AndyJ0076 In general, you can't. To statically determine the libraries loaded by a dynamically linked C program, you have to figure out if the program contains code to load a library with `dlopen`, then which libraries those are and whether the code ever reached the `dlopen` call. The latter two problems are undecidable. `strings`, `readelf` and `strace` are your friends, but they won't catch everything.

Comment: You can also set the environment variable `LD_DEBUG=files` before launching your program in order to see every library that is dynamically linked throughout the execution. It is very handy if you have a comprehensive test suite to automate the process, but it still pays off when you use your application manually.